# ssl/tls handshake analyzer

Tags: debugging, ssl

I'm trying to implement tls communication between a browser (using the forge js library) using socket.io as transport and a java application as the TLS server.
The tls traffic is base64 encoded so I cannot use a regular sniffer (like tcdump) to analyze the traffic; I can convert the traffic back to binary but it's still hard to interpret the tls records.
Is there a tool that can make sense of the messages but that does not expect any specific transport for the traffic?

Comment: "The tls traffic is base64 encoded". Really? Why? How does the browser know to base64-decode it?

Comment: The forge js library does the decoding/encoding; as far as I could tell the data was then stored in a normal string.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use Wireshark. If you're not using a port where SSL/TLS is normally used, you may have to right-click on a packet and choose *Decode As... -> SSL*.

(This being said, there's little point in implementing TLS within the browser using JavaScript: this is [not going to be secure](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/).)

Comment: It's not just the port, the traffic goes over websockets (socket.io) and is enclosed in a json message like {"tls_traffic" : "gC8BAwEABgAAACAAAC8AAP9RULD6laZWp1pVjBDHVhgJzbu15CoqDKjHnjGUukClgw=="}

Comment: That article does not apply in my case because I'm still going to use https to load the js and for certificate trusting; I'll then be using websockets for cross domain communication with third parties whose certificates I received/trusted from the https site that contained the js that implements TLS.

Comment: Sure, but it will still be very difficult for the user to verify anything about the communication with that 3rd party, even the fact that it's using TLS at all. You're likely to get mixed-content warnings.